# How to get all created types of an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, clr

How i can get all created types of an assembly when it's running ?
I used reflexion but it can retrieve all types but not just instantiated types.

Example: After Runing the assembly.exe I want to get

```
System.Object   10 Instances
System.String   102 Instances
System.Char[]  10 Instances ....
```

So how we can do it ?

Comment: All *instances* or all *types*?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov all instances mean all instantied types :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov means their is no solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not out of the box. You can look into [ClrMD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime).

Comment: Use Mono.Cecil to navigate into your assembly then you should count number of instances found for each type.

Comment: @MojtabaTajik do you have any docs or tutorials ?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  ClrMD helped me a lot thanks :)

Comment: @miloud You welcome :)